# Sending UDP packets from local to UDP server moto in Contiki Cooja

Tags: contiki, cooja

I am running a simulation in Cooja. My simulation has only 2 motos: an rpl border router, an rpl udp-server. I am using the example code given in Contiki: border-router.c and udp-server.c.

I am using "tunslip6" tool to create a bridge between the moto with my local machine(which is running on Ubuntu 18.04). Now, I want to access the rpl udp-server moto and want get a reply from my local machine to simulate access from outside the network. Can anyone suggest me how to do that? I am a newbie so any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You must go through rpl-udp example to simulate client server communication.The tunslip6 tool can be use to interface server with local machine.